# Como usar LOGGER em java

Tags: java, logging

Configurei o `Logger` na minha classe principal.

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DashBoard.class.getName());
```

e estou a usar deste modo:

```
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occur in FileHandler.", exception);
```

Contudo agora queria usar o mesmo ficheiro de log nas outras classes.

É boa pratica usar o `Logger` desta forma?

--> config.class

```
// devido a ter definido como static tenho acesso nas outras classes deste modo 
DashBoard.LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Loading... FxmlQualidade.fxml");
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizo o LoggerFactory do slf4j.

Para cada classe:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MinhaClasse.class);
```

Para utilizar (creio que os mais utilizados são o info, error, debug):

Ps: "{}" informa um valor de variável no LOG.

```
LOGGER.info("total time {} seconds", total);
```

ou

```
LOGGER.error("error whathever");
```